# how to overwrite property files in a docker container?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, deployment, jar, properties-file

I have a docker container inside which I have jar file that is of my springBoot application . How can I overwrite the application.property file of my app. Suppose if I want to change datasource url ,how can I do that through commandline?

Comment: Just for the clarification, you want to do it one time only or make that command a part of some automation script?

Comment: one time only ....just in case one of my properties changes ....like db url or port

Comment: Alright then, the answer I wrote should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Run `docker ps` and note the initials of id of your container.
2. Run `docker exec -it <id> <bash or sh>`, you will be inside your running container.
3. Go to your jar directory. Place your properties file in config/ as application.properties.
4. Rerun your app, but make sure to do it in background, so you can exit docker.

You can't restart the primary process (PID 1). For that usecase you'll need external volume and restart the container on property file change.

1. Create a volume: `docker volume create vol1`, you will get /var/lib/docker/volumes/vol1/
2. Change group of directory `sudo chgrp 1001 /var/lib/docker/volumes/vol1/_data`
3. Add write access to group: `sudo chmod g+w /var/lib/docker/volumes/vol1/_data`
4. Check the permissions of the directory: `sudo ls -al /var/lib/docker/volumes/vol1/`. They should be: `drwxrwxr-x`
5. Next time you run your container, mount the folder containing jar file to your volume as: `docker run -d --name=webApp1 --mount source=vol1,destination=/path/to/app -p port:port name`
6. You can change the property file in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/vol1/_data/` and restart container: `docker restart container_name`

**Disclaimer:** Replacing properties file outside jar is not considered a good practice and is highly discouraged. So, these steps are only recommended for testing.

Comment: nohup java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:application.properties,/app/override.propertie & ...... i tried your way ...but following command does'nt did the trick for me

Comment: didnt work..... i tried to replace server.port and it ddnt work for me ... as i tried to reRun the jar

Comment: can suggest me the way which worked for you .....when tried to replace property and rerun the app inside container

Comment: @Mr.Fix, can you do `ps -ef` inside container and see the process id for your initially running app? If it's the primary process you can't restart it. It was secondary for me. To make it work for the primary process you will have to create a volume and place jar file in that volume. Entry point should have command reading config  file outside jar. For this setup you'll just restart container for each config file change.

Comment: it is the primary process for me ... thats why i guess it is not working for me....if it primary..what are the exact steps that i need to follow

Comment: @Mr.Fix, I have added details to the main answer. Please use your entrypoint command for app that loads properties file outside the jar.